# find string in a cell array

Tags: string, cells

I want to test if the extension of a filename is in a list of extensions.

I tried it with strfind on a cell array but do not see how to get a boolean value out of the resulting matrix.

```
strfind({'tif'; 'jpg'},'jpg') % should give true
strfind({'tif'; 'jpg'},'bmp') % should give false
```

the first results in

```
[]
[1]
```

the second in

```
[]
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is wrap your original code with any()

```
>> any(strcmpi({'tif','jpg'},'jpg'))

ans =

     1

>> any(strcmpi({'tif','jpg'},'bmp'))

ans =

    0
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now using find:

```
    [~, ~, ext] = fileparts(imageFile);
    ext = strrep(ext, '.', '');
    listOfValidExt = {'tif'; 'jpg'};
    indices = find(cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x,ext), listOfValidExt), 1);
    if ~isempty(indices)
    ...
```